# Trying to installing new package and harmful "apt --fix-broken install" message

Tags: apt, 18.04, 20.04, package-management, software-installation

I want to install new package on ubuntu18.04 and I think I installed incorrectly some Ubuntu 20 packages and when I want to install some packages like:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
```

I got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtest-dev : Depends: googletest (= 1.10.0-2~18.04.sav0) but it is not going to be installed
 libncurses5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libncursesw5 : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libncursesw5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libtinfo-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But by running this command:`sudo apt --fix-broken install`  I got this message:

```
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

And as obvious in this message a dozen of packages will be removed. how could I do that without removing these packages.

Full message is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice acl amd64-microcode apg apport-symptoms appstream apt-config-icons aptdaemon-data aptitude-common avahi-utils blt bluez-obexd busybox-initramfs
  ca-certificates-java cheese-common cmake-data colord-data command-not-found-data cracklib-runtime cuda-command-line-tools-11-4 cuda-compiler-11-4
  cuda-cuobjdump-11-4 cuda-cupti-11-4 cuda-cupti-dev-11-4 cuda-cuxxfilt-11-4 cuda-documentation-11-4 cuda-gdb-11-4 cuda-libraries-11-4 cuda-libraries-dev-11-4
  cuda-memcheck-11-4 cuda-nsight-11-4 cuda-nsight-compute-11-4 cuda-nsight-systems-11-4 cuda-nvdisasm-11-4 cuda-nvml-dev-11-4 cuda-nvprof-11-4 cuda-nvprune-11-4
  cuda-nvrtc-11-4 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-4 cuda-nvtx-11-4 cuda-nvvp-11-4 cuda-samples-11-4 cuda-sanitizer-11-4 cuda-toolkit-11-4 cuda-tools-11-4 cuda-visual-tools-11-4
  cups-pk-helper cups-server-common dc debhelper dh-autoreconf dh-strip-nondeterminism diffstat distro-info distro-info-data dns-root-data dnsmasq-base
  docutils-common docutils-doc fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-elusive-icons fonts-font-awesome fonts-lato fonts-mathjax gcr gdal-data gdbserver gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-mutter-2 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0
  gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0
  gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-control-center-faces gnome-keyring-pkcs11
  gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-shell-common gnome-software-common gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data
  gnome-todo-common gnome-user-guide gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs-libs icu-devtools
  ifupdown initramfs-tools-bin intel-microcode intltool-debian ippusbxd iputils-arping iucode-tool javascript-common klibc-utils liba52-0.7.4 libaccountsservice0
  libalgorithm-c3-perl libappconfig-perl libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-cpio-perl libarchive-zip-perl libaribb24-0 libarmadillo8
  libarpack2 libart-2.0-2 libatasmart4 libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libatopology2 libavc1394-0 libavresample-dev libb-hooks-endofscope-perl
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libb64-0d libbabeltrace1 libbasicusageenvironment1 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-swap2
  libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libbluetooth3 libboost-atomic-dev libboost-container-dev libboost-context-dev libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-date-time-dev
  libboost-exception-dev libboost-fiber-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-log-dev
  libboost-math-dev libboost-mpi-dev libboost-numpy-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-random-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-signals-dev
  libboost-stacktrace-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev libboost-wave-dev libbrlapi0.6
  libc6-dbg libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcddb2 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio17 libcharls1 libclass-accessor-perl libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl
  libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-inspector-perl libclass-load-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-mix-perl libclass-singleton-perl
  libclass-std-fast-perl libclass-std-perl libclone-perl libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libconvert-binhex-perl libcpanel-json-xs-perl libcrack2
  libcrypt-eksblowfish-perl libcrypt-rijndael-perl libcryptsetup12 libcufft-11-4 libcufft-dev-11-4 libcupscgi1 libcupsmime1 libcurand-11-4 libcurand-dev-11-4
  libcusolver-11-4 libcusolver-dev-11-4 libcusparse-11-4 libcusparse-dev-11-4 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libdata-entropy-perl libdata-float-perl libdata-optlist-perl
  libdate-manip-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdbus-1-dev libdc1394-22-dev
  libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdevice-serialport-perl libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdrm-dev libdv4
  libdvbpsi10 libdw1 libdynaloader-functions-perl libebackend-1.2-10 libebml4v5 libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-28
  libegl1-mesa-dev libemail-date-format-perl libemail-valid-perl libepoxy-dev libepsilon1 libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libexempi3 libexif-dev
  libexif-doc libexporter-tiny-perl libfftw3-single3 libfile-sharedir-perl libfile-slurp-perl libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libfreexl1 libfyba0 libgail-3-0
  libgdal20 libgdcm2-dev libgdcm2.8 libgdm1 libgeos-3.6.2 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff2 libgif7 libgjs0g libgl1-mesa-dev libgl2ps1.4 libgles1 libgles2-mesa-dev
  libglu1-mesa libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-todo libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgom-1.0-0
  libgphoto2-dev libgpm2 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgraphite2-dev libgrilo-0.3-0 libgroupsock8 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common
  libgutenprint2 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-openmpi-100 libhpmud0 libhttp-lite-perl libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3
  libilmbase-dev libimage-base-bundle-perl libimage-info-perl libimobiledevice6 libio-interface-perl libio-pty-perl libio-sessiondata-perl libio-socket-multicast-perl
  libio-string-perl libio-stringy-perl libipc-run-perl libjs-jquery libjs-mathjax libjs-modernizr libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libjson-maybexs-perl libjwt0
  libklibc libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 libldb1 liblept5 liblirc-client0 liblist-moreutils-perl liblivemedia62 liblua5.1-0 liblua5.3-0 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common libmad0 libmail-sendmail-perl libmatroska6v5 libmediaart-2.0-0 libmicrodns0 libmime-lite-perl libmime-tools-perl libmime-types-perl libminizip1
  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmozjs-52-0 libmpdec2 libmpeg2-4 libmro-compat-perl libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmutter-2-0
  libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libndp0 libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-sftp-foreign-perl libnetcdf-c++4
  libnetcdf13 libnetplan0 libnfs11 libnm0 libnma0 libnpp-11-4 libnpp-dev-11-4 libnss-myhostname libntfs-3g88 libnumber-bytes-human-perl libnvidia-cfg1-470
  libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvjpeg-11-4
  libnvjpeg-dev-11-4 libodbc1 libogdi3.2 libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-calib3d3.2 libopencv-core-dev libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-features2d-dev
  libopencv-features2d3.2 libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-flann3.2 libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-highgui3.2 libopencv-imgcodecs-dev libopencv-imgcodecs3.2
  libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ml3.2 libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-objdetect3.2 libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo3.2
  libopencv-shape-dev libopencv-shape3.2 libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-stitching3.2 libopencv-superres-dev libopencv-superres3.2 libopencv-ts-dev
  libopencv-video-dev libopencv-video3.2 libopencv-videoio-dev libopencv-videoio3.2 libopencv-videostab-dev libopencv-videostab3.2 libopenexr-dev libopengl0
  libopenmpt-modplug1 liborc-0.4-dev liborc-0.4-dev-bin libossp-uuid-perl libossp-uuid16 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpackagekit-glib2-18
  libpadwalker-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validationcompiler-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl libparted-fs-resize0 libpcre16-3
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpeas-common libperlio-gzip-perl libphonenumber7 libphp-serialization-perl libpixman-1-dev libplacebo4 libplist3
  libplymouth4 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpq5 libproj12 libproxy-tools libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython3.6-minimal libqhull7 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libraw1394-dev libraw1394-tools libreadline5
  libreadonly-perl libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl libregina3 libresid-builder0c2a librhash0 librole-tiny-perl libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsdl2-2.0-0
  libserf-1-1 libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsidplay2 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libsoap-lite-perl libsoap-wsdl-perl libsocket++1 libspatialite7
  libspecio-perl libssh2-1 libstartup-notification0 libstemmer0d libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl
  libsub-quote-perl libsuperlu5 libsvn1 libsys-cpu-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl libsys-meminfo-perl libsys-mmap-perl libsysmetrics1 libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla
  libtalloc2 libtask-weaken-perl libtbb-dev libtbb2 libteamdctl0 libtemplate-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtesseract4 libtevent0 libtext-levenshtein-perl libtiff-dev
  libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libudisks2-0 libupnp6 libupower-glib3 liburi-encode-perl liburiparser1 libusageenvironment3 libusbmuxd4 libuv1 libva-wayland2
  libvariable-magic-perl libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libwayland-bin libwayland-dev libwbclient0 libwhoopsie-preferences0 libwhoopsie0 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common
  libx11-xcb-dev libxapian30 libxatracker2 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-res0
  libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-xv0 libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxerces-c3.2 libxfixes-dev
  libxfont2 libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxklavier16 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-namespacesupport-perl libxml-sax-base-perl libxml-sax-expat-perl
  libxml-sax-perl libxml-simple-perl libxml2-utils libxmlrpc-lite-perl libxnvctrl0 libxrandr-dev libxres1 libxshmfence-dev libxtst-dev libxvmc1 libxxf86vm-dev
  libyaml-0-2 libyaml-libyaml-perl libzeitgeist-2.0-0 lintian linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-sound-base
  llvm-6.0 llvm-6.0-runtime mesa-common-dev mobile-broadband-provider-info mpi-default-bin mscompress mutter-common nautilus-data ncurses-term nsight-compute-2021.2.2
  nsight-systems-2021.3.2 nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-utils-470 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 opencv-data openssh-sftp-server p11-kit p11-kit-modules
  pandoc pandoc-data patchutils php-apcu php-apcu-bc php-gd php-intl php7.2-gd php7.2-intl po-debconf proj-bin proj-data python-apt-common python-babel-localedata
  python-minimal python-pip-whl python-qtawesome-common python2.7-minimal python3-minimal python3.6-minimal rhythmbox-data session-migration sgml-base sphinx-common
  sphinx-rtd-theme-common spyder-common syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy t1utils thermald tk8.6-blt2.5 totem-common usbmuxd vim-runtime vlc-bin vlc-data
  vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization wayland-protocols whoopsie-preferences x11-apps
  x11-session-utils x11-xkb-utils x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-record-dev x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xbitmaps xbrlapi xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-scalable xfonts-utils xinit xinput xml-core xserver-common xserver-xephyr
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xwayland zeitgeist-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbrotli-dev libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-i386 libfreetype-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libgnutls30 libgsm1 libharfbuzz0b libhogweed6
  liblcms2-2 libnettle8 libp11-kit0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libtasn1-6 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvulkan1 p11-kit-modules
  timgm6mb-soundfont zlib1g zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc freetype2-doc gnutls-bin fluid-soundfont-gm fluidsynth timidity musescore
Recommended packages:
  mesa-vulkan-drivers | vulkan-icd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alsa-base alsa-utils apache2 apparmor apport apport-gtk aptdaemon aptitude apturl apturl-common aspell aspell-en bluez bluez-cups brltty cheese cmake colord
  command-not-found cuda cuda-11-4 cuda-demo-suite-11-4 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-470 cuda-runtime-11-4 cups cups-browsed cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  dbus-user-session deepstream-6.0 deja-dup dh-python dstat eog evolution-data-server fdisk ffmpeg firefox foomatic-db-compressed-ppds friendly-recovery fuse gdb
  gdisk gdm3 gedit gedit-common gir1.2-gst-rtsp-server-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-session-bin gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell
  gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap gnome-startup-applications gnome-terminal gnome-todo gnome-video-effects gnupg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse hplip hplip-data htop ibus ibus-table iio-sensor-proxy
  indicator-stickynotes init initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core irqbalance language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libaa1 libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libatk1.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev libavdevice57 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-part2 libboost-all-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.65-dev
  libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev libboost-mpi-python1.65.1 libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.65-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.65-dev
  libcaca0 libcairo2-dev libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libcwidget3v5 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
  libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstrtspserver-1.0-0 libgstrtspserver-1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libjson-glib-dev
  libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libncursesw5-dev libnss-systemd libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-contrib3.2 libopencv-dev libopencv-viz-dev libopencv-viz3.2
  libopencv3.2-java libopencv3.2-jni libpam-systemd libpango1.0-dev libpeas-1.0-0 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev
  libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev libpython3.6-stdlib libreadline-gplv2-dev librhythmbox-core10 libsane1
  libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsmbclient libtinfo-dev libtotem0 libvolume-key1 libvtk6.3 llvm-6.0-dev lsb-release media-player-info mercurial mercurial-common
  mount mtr-tiny mutter nano nautilus nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal nautilus-share netplan.io network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome networkd-dispatcher nplan ntfs-3g nvidia-driver-470 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
  openprinting-ppds openssh-server orca packagekit packagekit-tools pinentry-curses pinentry-gnome3 plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 ppp pppconfig pppoeconf pptp-linux printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-gutenprint
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-splix procps
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pyflakes pyflakes3 pylint python python-alabaster python-all python-all-dev python-asn1crypto python-astroid python-babel
  python-backports-abc python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-bleach python-certifi python-cffi-backend python-chardet
  python-cloudpickle python-concurrent.futures python-configparser python-crypto python-cryptography python-dateutil python-dbus python-decorator python-dev
  python-docutils python-egenix-mxdatetime python-egenix-mxtools python-entrypoints python-enum34 python-funcsigs python-functools32 python-gi python-gi-dev
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-html5lib python-idna python-imagesize python-ipaddress python-ipykernel python-ipython python-ipython-genutils python-isort
  python-jedi python-jinja2 python-jsonschema python-jupyter-client python-jupyter-core python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-lazy-object-proxy
  python-logilab-common python-markupsafe python-mccabe python-mistune python-mock python-nbconvert python-nbformat python-numpy python-numpydoc python-olefile
  python-openssl python-pandocfilters python-parso python-pathlib2 python-pbr python-pexpect python-pickleshare python-pil python-pip python-pkg-resources
  python-prompt-toolkit python-psutil python-ptyprocess python-pycodestyle python-pyflakes python-pygments python-pyqt5 python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
  python-pyqt5.qtopengl python-pyqt5.qtsvg python-pyqt5.qtwebkit python-qtawesome python-qtconsole python-qtpy python-requests python-roman python-rope python-scandir
  python-secretstorage python-setuptools python-simplegeneric python-singledispatch python-sip python-six python-sphinx python-sphinx-rtd-theme python-spyder
  python-svn python-talloc python-testpath python-tk python-tornado python-traitlets python-typing python-tz python-urllib3 python-wcwidth python-webencodings
  python-wheel python-wrapt python-xdg python-zmq python2.7 python2.7-dev python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-asn1crypto python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-certifi python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-click python3-colorama python3-commandnotfound
  python3-crypto python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dateutil python3-dbus python3-debconf python3-debian python3-defer python3-dev
  python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gst-1.0 python3-httplib2 python3-idna python3-keyring
  python3-keyrings.alt python3-launchpadlib python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-lazr.uri python3-lib2to3 python3-libnvinfer python3-libnvinfer-dev python3-louis
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-nacl python3-netifaces python3-numpy python3-oauth python3-olefile python3-opencv python3-pexpect
  python3-pil python3-pip python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-ptyprocess python3-pyatspi python3-pyflakes python3-pymacaroons
  python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-rfc3339 python3-secretstorage python3-setuptools
  python3-simplejson python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-tz python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-urllib3
  python3-virtualenv python3-wadllib python3-wheel python3-xdg python3-xkit python3-yaml python3-zope.interface python3.6 python3.6-dev rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins rtkit samba-libs sane-utils screen-resolution-extra seahorse simple-scan snapd snapd-xdg-open
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk spyder ssh-import-id system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev systemd
  systemd-sysv sysvinit-utils the totem totem-plugins ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session ubuntu-software ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service udev udisks2 ufw unattended-upgrades update-manager
  update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk util-linux vim virtualenv vlc vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-samba
  vlc-plugin-video-output whoopsie xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04 zoneminder zoneminder-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbrotli-dev libfreetype-dev libhogweed6 libnettle8 timgm6mb-soundfont
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-i386 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libgnutls30 libgsm1 libharfbuzz0b liblcms2-2 libp11-kit0 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libtasn1-6 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvulkan1 p11-kit-modules zlib1g zlib1g-dev
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  fdisk libncursesw5 (due to fdisk) init systemd-sysv (due to init) mount util-linux (due to mount) sysvinit-utils
23 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 500 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,986 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Comment: This looks like a *very broken* package database. It seems to me the most sensible option is to reinstall your system, I'm not sure this is recoverable.

Comment: @ArturMeinild but, I just installed one or two packages not more. Why should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Because your `apt` database looks seriously broken. I don't know how it got to this state, but something is definitely not as it should be. And I don't know how to recover from what you're showing, except to reinstall. I would reinstall if my system wrote what yours do.

Comment: absolutely the first one is far away from my question